# How to determine the standard error of the prediction from an MLR?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, standard-error

I have a multiple linear regression model that I have built in SAS that's fairly simple: it predicts someone's blood pressure based on four variables: age, race, gender, and level of depression.

proc reg data=dummy;
model Blood Pressure = Depression Age Gender Race ;
quit;

I was using this model to predict the blood pressure of a person with a given level of depression, age, gender, and race (for example, a 50 year old white woman with a history of mild depression), which is simple enough. But how do I find the standard error of that prediction? If I have a model that is essentially:

y = B0 + B1X1 + B2X2 + B3X3 + B4X4, how do I find the standard error of one prediction of that model? Is it just the MSE as reported by SAS?

Comment: Change proc reg to proc glm, add an statement "estimete ..." Check the sas manual on support.sas.com for detail.